# Passing a node.js script an argument with a space on Windows

Tags: node.js, arguments

I'm running a node script from the command line on Windows and am trying to pass in a folder path that includes a space. When accessing this argument, via require modules or via the `process.argv` variable I don't seem to get what I would expect. For the following command:

```
node script.js "C:\path\to\folder\with a space\"
```

I seem to get the following value:

> process.argv[2] = C:\path\to\folder\with a space\"

Notice the trailing `"` in the string. If the argument is passed without quotes, it obviously passes it as different arguments split on the space.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug? And if it is a bug, is there a possible workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trailing backslash escapes the quote which is then again implied by the shell (instead of aborting due to lack of a closing quote).

The fix is simply escaping that backslash with another backslash or omitting it altogether:

```
C:\Users\myself> python -c "import sys; print sys.argv[1]" "foo\bar\"
foo\bar"
C:\Users\myself> python -c "import sys; print sys.argv[1]" "foo\bar\\"
foo\bar\
```

Note that you may only escape the *last* backslash this way - any other backslash ins the string will not act as an escape character:

```
C:\Users\myself> python -c "import sys; print sys.argv[1]" "foo\\bar\\"
foo\\bar\
```

Comment: Wow, I feel really stupid for not considering that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Blame the *great* cmd.exe shell for simply ignoring obviously incorrect quoting.

Comment: This is not a shell bug. If you run Node by the CreateProcess WInApi function where the shell is not involved, you will get the same issue in Node. Moreover, if you run the following command in the Windows `cmd` shell you will get the expected result: `find "\root\" log.txt`. But you'll probably find the same issue in PowerShell. This is a coincidence that Node and PowerShell have the same issue.